# reformating cakephp find threaded

Tags: json, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

My goal is to use a tree object to store invoices.  The issue I'm running into is that it always puts a "Invoice" model wrapper around each subsequent child.  I tried just getting the results and using the Set class to clean up the redundant "Invoice", "children" but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work.  I'm using this in an API so basically what I want to be able to do is move up and down the array without having to constantly do invoice.children.invoice.children

In my controller I have:

```
  $results = $this->Invoice->find('threaded', array(
      'order' => array('lft ASC') // or array('id ASC')
      ));

  $this->set(array(
    'results' => $results,
    '_serialize' => 'results'
    ));
```

What I'm getting is:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "parent_id": null,
            "lft": 1,
            "rght": 30,
            "name": "Invoices",
            "children": [
                {
                    "Invoice": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "parent_id": 1,
                        "lft": 2,
                        "rght": 15,
                        "text": "invoice 001"
                    },
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "Invoice": {
                                "id": 3,
                                "parent_id": 2,
                                "lft": 3,
                                "rght": 8,
                                "text": "invoice_item"
                            },
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "Invoice": {
                                        "id": 4,
                                        "parent_id": 3,
                                        "lft": 4,
                                        "rght": 5,
                                        "text": "invoice_sub_item"
                                    },
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "Invoice": {
                                        "id": 5,
                                        "parent_id": 3,
                                        "lft": 6,
                                        "rght": 7,
                                        "text": "subitem#2"
                                    },
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Ideally I'd like to have

```
invoices.invoice.text = "invoice 001"
```

and

```
invoices.invoice.invoice_item[0].text  = "invoice_item"
```

Obviously I'll need to add/take away from the array and resubmit with changes. Is this possible or am I just making things harder on myself?

Comment: What's the purpose of using a *tree* structure for this? I've never ever got an invoice displayed or printed that had a tree structure. This doesn't make any sense at all?

Comment: Multiple line items and multiple sub items under those line items???  That doesn't sound like a tree?!?

Comment: @JustinYoung So you are saying for 3 components of an invoice, viz., **invoice details**, **line-items** and **sub-items** (whatever it means?!!), you are able to use a single table?!! How?? What type of columns (names) did you use in the table? I can only see this as 2 models `Invoice HABTM Product`. Of course, there will be `InvoicesProduct` model too...leading to 3 tables in all... so that's not a tree structure!